# Wordpress ajax very slow and can't retrieve post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing a simple wordpress ajax but the response is very slow and I can't retrieve the data. Here's my code

**JS**

```
function getProductData(idObj) {
    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {'action':'get_product_data','data':'asdasd'}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
function get_product_data() {
    echo $_POST['data'];
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_product_data', 'get_product_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_product_data', 'get_product_data');
```

The response is always 0 and it takes 12 seconds to respond.

Comment: can u remove 2 last lines and run it again. it must be about 1 sec to get response (test purpose)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `die()` or `wp_die()` at the end of the get_product_data function:

```
function get_product_data() {
    echo $_POST['data'];
    die();
}
```

Comment: I tried using wp_send_json_success() which has wp_die() and with that, I can output the response. But still I'm not able to retrieve the post data.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this code but I hope it works for you.

```
JS: Change

           function getProductData(idObj) {

                $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {'action':'get_product_data','data':'asdasd'}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }

        to 

        function getProductData(idObj) {
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-dmin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
        action: 'get_post_data',
        'myecho': myecho,
        }

    PHP: change 

    function get_product_data() {
        $myecho = $_POST['data'];
        echo $myecho;
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_get_product_data', 'get_product_data');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_product_data', 'get_product_data');
```